# How to Style <Link> using styled-component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I was using this `Link` from `@material-ui/core/Link` in my TypeScript code and it worked perfectly:

```
<Link href="#" variant="body2">
  Forgot?
</Link>
```

However, I am trying to switch to `styled-components` placed in another file. Now, I am trying to use this (eg: https://styled-components.com/docs/basics):

```
const Link = ({ className, children}) => (
  <a className={className}>
    {children}
  </a>
);

export const StyledLink = styled(Link)`
  href: #;
  variant: body2;
`;
```

along with:

```
<StyledLink>Forgot?</StyledLink>
```

But I keep getting errors on `className` and `children` that `Binding element 'children' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031`but even if I add `any`, It doesn't work.

What is the correct way to use styled-components in this case? Or any other `css-in-js` alternative?

Comment: I wait for your second question re-production or another Stack Overflow question. but now I leave an upvote. +1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should make your `Link` component just like below:

```
// Link.js
import { Link } from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import styled from 'styled-components';

export default styled(Link)`
  display: block;
  color: #F51963;
  text-decoration: none;
`;
```

Comment: and how would I pass an actual website link through it? I tried with ```<StyledLink href={'www.hotmaill.com'}>Forgot Password?</StyledLink>``` but it didn't work.

Comment: Nevermind. It works if I add ```href: #;```in the style list. Any idea what this # represents here?

Comment: Dear @Jnl, for passing `href` just import your custom `Link` component where ever you wanna use, then write like `<Link href="www.hotmail.com">sampleText</Link>`. it should work and there is no need to passing `href: #` inside your style because it is not a valid CSS property name. for more information please upload your re-production on CodeSandBox and definitely, I will see your code and your stack.

Answer (score 0):

This code works, and gets no warnings from the typescript compiler

```js
import styled from "styled-components";

const Link = ({
  className,
  children
}: {
  readonly className: string;
  readonly children: React.ReactElement;
}) => (
  <a href="/" className={className}>
    {children}
  </a>
);

export const StyledLink = styled(Link)`
  href: #;
  variant: body2;
  color: red;
`;

function App() {
  return (
    <StyledLink className="classic">
      <div>Forgot?</div>
    </StyledLink>
  );
}
```

Comment: What exactly does ```href: #;```signify here? I am trying to use the accepted answer here but If I pass ```href={www.hello.com}```in my ```StyledLink```component, it doesn't work. However, if I add ```href: #;```in the style list it works.

Comment: If you want to link to a site you should change the href above, e.g. `<a href="www.hello.com" className={className}>`

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `<Link>` on top of other divs or buttons for example

`<Link><button className="Btn">Forgot?</button></Link>`

you can then do two things to style the button / divs

`<Link><button className="Btn" style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>Forgot?</button></Link>`

or the second is import a separate css file

```
import classes from './ComponentName.module.css'
```

and then give a style

`<Link><button className={classes.Btn}>Forgot?</button></Link>`

Comment: This produces invalid HTML as you can't put a button inside a link.